# Distinguishing between placed received and non-received calls

Tags: lg-optimus-one, user-interface, call-history

On my Android phone, under the list of all phone calls, there are several distinct icons to distinguish between:

- outgoing calls (a green arrow pointing away from the phone)
- missed calls (a red arrow bouncing off the phone)
- received calls (a blue arrow pointing into the phone)

However, the user interface does not distinguish between placed calls which were answered on the other end and calls which were not answered on the other end.

Does anyone have a user interface which distinguishes between these two scenarios or does anyone know of an upgrade I may perform in the user interface (perhaps even by going as far as installing CyanogenMod) so as to account for this difference in the user interface?

I am running Android 2.3.4 (GingerBread) on an LG Optimus Net P690.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a new dialer which supports this. I have tried Swipe Dialer Free and it does this (You get the same icon for all outgoing calls whether they were answered or not but for the un-answered call, you will have "Not Answered" mentioned"

P.S. - If your dialer shows the duration of call then I think for Non-Answered outgoing calls, it will show "0m 0s". All other calls will have different durations. So, you can differentiate between them (if this is what your purpose is).

Comment: True, unanswered calls show "0 mins 0 secs" although you need to click on the entry in the call log in order to see this, but otherwise you're right.